# How To Create Modal With Transparent Background?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using the docs (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#transparent-modals) to upgrade from React Navigation 4 to React Navigation 5.

In Version 4 I had a Modal Stack that had a transparent background, meaning I could see the screen of the stack below it.

In version 5, I'm using the docs to try the same move but not getting anywhere - how can I make the modal background transparent?

```
            const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

            function Modal() {
              return (
                  <Tab.Navigator
                    headerMode='none'
                    screenOptions={{
                      cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
                      cardOverlayEnabled: true,}}
                    mode='modal'
                    >
                    <Tab.Screen
                      name="Photo"
                      component={AddPhotoModal}
                      options={{ animationEnabled: true, headerShown: false, tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="image" size={20} color="grey" /> }} />
                    <Tab.Screen
                      name="Camera"
                      component={ModalCamera}
                      options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="camera" size={20} color="grey" /> }} />
                    <Tab.Screen
                      name="Thoughts"
                      component={AddTextModal}
                      options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="font" size={20} color="grey" /> }} />
                  </Tab.Navigator>
              );
            }

            const Stack = createStackNavigator();

            function Main() {
              return (
                    <Stack.Navigator
                      initialRouteName="Home"
                    >
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="Vault"
                        component={VaultScreen}
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                      />
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="Post"
                        component={PostScreen}
                        options={{ title: 'View Post' }}
                      />
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name="Settings"
                        component={SettingsScreen}
                        options={{ title: 'Settings' }}
                      />
                    </Stack.Navigator>
              );
            }

            function App() {
              return (
                  <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
                      <NavigationContainer>
                        <Stack.Navigator
                          initialRouteName="Home"
                          mode='modal'
                          screenOptions={{
                              cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
                              cardOverlayEnabled: true
                          }}
                        >
                          <Stack.Screen
                            name="Vault"
                            component={Main}
                            options={{ headerShown: false }}
                          />
                          <Stack.Screen
                            name="Modal"
                            component={Modal}
                            options={{ headerShown: false }}
                          />
                        </Stack.Navigator>
                    </NavigationContainer>
                </PaperProvider>
              );
            }

            export default App;
```

Thanks.